First Migration with alembic not created table in fastApi
When run command for create my first migration with one table, do not create table, the script that created is empty in functions upgrade and downgrade and only create table alembic_version
I understand that it should contain something like:
op.create_table(
  'task',
   sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
   sa.Column('name', sa.String(20), nullable=False),
   sa.Column('description', sa.String(200)),
    sa.Column('status', sa.String(20)),
 )

I'm missing something?
env.py
from logging.config import fileConfig

from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool

from alembic import context
from database.database import Base, engine


# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config

# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
if config.config_file_name is not None:
    fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support
# from myapp import mymodel
# target_metadata = mymodel.Base.metadata
target_metadata = Base.metadata
print("-->", Base.metadata.tables)


# other values from the config, defined by the needs of env.py,
# can be acquired:
# my_important_option = config.get_main_option("my_important_option")
# ... etc.


def run_migrations_offline() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    context.configure(
        url=url,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        literal_binds=True,
        dialect_opts={"paramstyle": "named"}
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section, {}),
        prefix="sqlalchemy.",
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )
  
    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection, 
            target_metadata=target_metadata
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()

database.py conection to data base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker ,declarative_base


DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://postgres:postgres@192.168.1.11:5432/lean"
engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL,pool_pre_ping=True, pool_size=20, max_overflow=30)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()



How did you generate the migration? Did you supply --autogenerate as a parameter? Did you import your model classes in your alembic environment (usually named env.py) so that they're visible to Alembic? Otherwise an empty migration that you're supposed to fill out yourself is created. Please add the relevant details as text to your question, as images are hard to search, isn't compatible with most screen readers and can't be copy-pasted properly.

env.py imports Base from database.py for metadata, but it doesn't import models.py, so there is no way python will ever know about Task. You need to import models.py as well. Although there is no env.py imports at your screenshots, this is most probably the problem you are witnessing

@sudden_appearance  I was very right, but then if you add another model, should I also add it there?

you need to import .py files, that contain your models (derived from Base). That way these models will be initialized at runtime and Base.metadata will register those in metadata and alembic will successfully find them at revision stage
